# Help understanding this nhibernate session management code snippet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

This is based on: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx

Code is here: https://gist.github.com/852307

My questions are, in the DAO:

```
//Example of dao
public class Dao<T> : IDao<T>
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Dao(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void Save(T transient)
    {
        sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(transient);
    }
}
```

I guess the ISessionFactory get's autoatically wired up using windsor correct?

```
public class NHibernateInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                               .UsingFactoryMethod(k => BuildSessionFactory()));

        container.Register(Component.For<NHibernateSessionModule>());

        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactoryProvider>().AsFactory());

        container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<ISessionFactory>>()
                                    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.ResolveAll<ISessionFactory>()));

        HttpContext.Current.Application[SessionFactoryProvider.Key]
                        = container.Resolve<ISessionFactoryProvider>();
    }

    #endregion
    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory() { ... }
}
```

But in the DAO, when the method is called:

```
sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
```

How does this snippet and the HttpModule that opens the session work?

**I don't see how GetCurrentSession() hooks into the session that was opened by the HttpModule since GetCurrentSession is a built in method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using NHibernate contextual sessions:
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session

All the magic happens in **LazySessionContext**.  Whenever the bind method is called this saves the session in an nhibernate **context**.  In your case the context would be **LazySessionContext** which is a custom context (inherits from NH's ICurrentSessionContext) used by this application.  There are 4 or 5 different types of standard contextual sessions in version 3.2 of nhibernate.

The **GetCurrentSession** method basically retrieves your saved (saved session in bind call) NH session from earlier.

Comment: So in a web application, where does it get saved? In HttpContext.Current.Request.Items?

Comment: From the source code in your link it looks like it stores it in HttpContext.Current.Items[CurrentSessionContextKey].